# How to make Identity Server to add claims for given scope?

Tags: blazor, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

I have server hosting my Blazor Webasm, I have Blazor Webasm, and I have my backend REST service. Those 3 I control (i.e. can change the code). Authorization is done thanks to Identity Server (here, I cannot change code).

So far it works like this, user sees the web page, logs in, make some action, request is send to REST service, authorization and claims are verified (some actions require having admin claim). It works.

But now I wanted to hide admin-actions from regular users, to do this I would like to check the claim. And the problem is, while REST service sees the claims, blazor does not -- it has only a handful of "default" claims, but not for my scope.

REST service has very simplistic configuration:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
  {
    options.Authority = "identityserver_addresss";
  });
```

while Blazor webasm uses this:

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication((RemoteAuthenticationOptions<OidcProviderOptions> options) =>
{
  // Configure your authentication provider options here.
  // For more information, see https://aka.ms/blazor-standalone-auth
  builder.Configuration.Bind("oidc", options.ProviderOptions);
});

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("api")
  .AddHttpMessageHandler(sp =>
  {
    var handler = sp.GetService<AuthorizationMessageHandler>()!
                  .ConfigureHandler(
                    authorizedUrls: "rest_service_address",
                    scopes: new[] { "my_scope" });
    return handler;
  });
```

and configuration has entry:

```
  "oidc": {
    "DefaultScopes": [
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "my_scope"
    ],
  }
```

So on surface it looks OK to me, I am telling which scope I am interested in, the REST service gets it, but I cannot figure out, why blazor wasm does not see it (it sees only "default" claims, user id, user name).

So how to tell blazor wasm to get the claims from given scope, or how to tell IS to include them for blazor as well?

*For checking what claims I got in Blazor wasm, I am printing all the claims from `AuthorizeView.Context.User`*.

**Update**

Blazor token decoded (taken from "userinfo" request):

```
{
  "nbf": 1644922079,
  "exp": 1645051679,
  "iss": "https://identityserver_address",
  "aud": [
    "https://identityserver_address/resources",
    "my_app_rc"
  ],
  "client_id": "my_app_client",
  "sub": "-guid-",
  "auth_time": 1642149284,
  "idp": "local",
  "my_app_claim_type": [
    "user",
    "admin"
  ],
  "jti": "ae61d547b81c970c135f2a13fb5e353a",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "my_scope"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

Visible claim types from the code:

```
sid
sub
auth_time
idp
amr
name
preferred_username
```

So the token (at least transferred) has the information I am looking for (claims kept in "my_app_claim_type" entry), yet from code I don't see it (I see some more claims not present in token, but it is another story).

Answer (score 1):

The claims that the client sees and what the REST API's sees are usually different. The claims seen by the client are the ones in the ID-token while the claims the API sees are the ones inside the access token. Your blazor client should not care or look inside the access token as it is only mean to be consumed by your APIs.

Can you add a sample ID-token and access token to your question?

In the API, you can set this to false to avoid claims from being renamed:

```
// Or set this flag to false
.AddJwtBearer(opt =>
{
    ...
    opt.MapInboundClaims = false;
});
```

or add these two lines:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 // By default, Microsoft has some legacy claim mapping that converts
    // standard JWT claims into proprietary ones. This removes those mappings.
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultOutboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

In the client, you can add the above two lines, and as well try the following:
(inside AddOpenIdConnect())

```
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("website", "website");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("gender", "gender");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("birthdate", "birthdate");
```

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Ok, thank you, I added the token (decoded) and visible claims. As for "should not care" -- well, to improve UX I would like to disable or hide given actions for some users (not a security measure, pure UX). To do so, I need to know if given action is applicable for the user. The shortest way would be to check the claims.

Comment: Does my updated answer help?

Comment: Thank you, I skipped REST service for now, because it is (in a way) irrelevant here, and focused on blazor webasm. The problem with the mapping you show is that `AddOidcAuthentication` does not have such member "ClaimActions", and the one you pointed "AddOpenIdConnect" comes from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect which is not supported in webasm.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63030480/unable-to-map-okta-groups-claim-to-roles-claim-in-blazor-wasm-client